# Access video from aws s3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-s3

I was previously accessing video files from local. Now I am attempting to access video files that are located on aws s3.

My old html element was

```
<source class="video-source" type="video/mp4" src="~/Content/videos/MyVideo.mp4" />
```

I should be able to do something like

```
<source class="video-source" type="video/mp4" src="AwsInfo" />
```

Also I have the following method in my controller

```
using (AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client())
{
    var bucketObject = new GetObjectRequest
    {
         BucketName = "MyBucketName",
         Key = "MyKey"
    };

    var v = client.GetObject(bucketObject); //I believe this would give me any information I need
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) which gives you a domain that you then access via url + key

```
<source class="video-source" type="video/mp4" src="https://myUrl.cloudfront.net/myKey" />
```